# Parse Server file size limit 20MB

Tags: ios, ssh, filesize, parse-server

Does anyone know how to change the file size limit for parse server?  at the moment i can properly download and upload files unto 20MB but i need to go a bit larger.

There is link on GitHub

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/src/Routers/FilesRouter.js#L21

but i can not figure out how to change this in the server end.  explored every part of the project through SSH and can not see a fielsrouter.js

**EDIT:** the server.js file now contains the variable maxUploadSize

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var app = express();
// Specify the connection string for your mongodb database
// and the location to your Parse cloud code
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: "XXXXX",
    cloud: "XXXXX",
    appId: “XXXXX”,
    masterKey: “XXXXX”,
    fileKey: “XXXXX”,
    serverURL: ‘XXXXX’,
    maxUploadSize: = '50mb'
});
// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
app.use('/parse', api);

var port = 1337;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server running on port ' + port);
});

//Parse Dashboard
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
    apps: [
        {
            appName: “XXXXX”,
            appId: “XXXXX”,
            masterKey: “XXXXX”,
            fileKey: “XXXXX”,
            production: true,
            serverURL: ‘XXXXX’,
           // maxUploadSize: = '50mb'
        }
    ]
});

var allowInsecureHTTP = true;

// Serve the Parse Dashboard on the /parsedashboard URL prefix
app.use('/', dashboard);

var portdash = 4040;
app.listen(portdash, function() {
    console.log('parse-dashboard running on port ' + portdash);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `maxUploadSize` to whatever you need it to be.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/ab06055369efee1e456dfdf5c3a86ceba0f4faf1/src/ParseServer.js

But i would suggest you also check the nginx `client_max_body_size` too.

Update:

**Bitnami configuration**:

Edit the `/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/server.js` file and insert the credentials

Then restart

```
   sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart parse
```

Comment: Ive come across this searching, but i can't figure out how to find that file to modify it.  I'm using amazon ec2 and logging on through SSH but can't find parse-server.js in any of the directories.  I've only just started playing with server side stuff

Comment: Are you using elastic beanstalk?

Comment: No I think it was just a preconfigured bitnami parse service directly under the ec2 option in aws.  The configuration options seem limited maybe I should look into something more customizable

Comment: Thanks man.  your going to laugh but now i just get message "could not start parse".  i did just paste the whole file from the above link in though.  Not sure what modifications it needed.

Comment: @WanderingScouse Unfortunately you can not do it like that. That file i asked you to edit is your config file.  You just need to add maxUploadSize and set the limit to that file. Look at the format and add it below the other variables. Im not sure if Bitnami allows it like that but its worth a try.

Comment: cloud: './cloud/main.js',
     appId: 'APP-ID',
     masterKey: 'MASTER-KEY',
     fileKey: 'FILE-KEY', maxUploadSize: '40mb'

Comment: notch, makes more sense than what i did ha!..  adding the maxUpladSize: = '40mb' won't let me restart the server.

Comment: Post the config for me plz! Could be a syntax issue. Double check your logs

Comment: In " maxUpladSize: = '40mb' " remove the '=' and it will work